# How to use callback function inside setState function

Tags: reactjs

I have simple click handler and it works in this case:

```
        handleClick = () => {
            const { isCalendarOpen } = this.state;

            this.setState ({ isCalendarOpen: !isCalendarOpen });
        };
```

But I must use callback function in setState, so I try this way:

```
       this.setState(state => ({
           isCalenderOpen: !state.isCalenderOpen
       }));
```

It's not wirking :( can someone suggest how to solve the problem?

Comment: "t's not wirking :(" not working how? How do you check it is working? Remember `setState` is async.

Comment: Also you have a typo `isCalend**e**rOpen` vs `isCalend**a**rOpen`

Answer (score 2):

In `setState`, second argument is the callback function which will be called after state has been set. The first argument is either the object to which state would be updated or a function which will return the updated state. In both of your cases you are updating the state. It should be

```
this.setState ({ isCalendarOpen: !isCalendarOpen }, () => {
  // callback function
});
```

or

```
this.setState(state => ({
       isCalenderOpen: !state.isCalenderOpen
   }), () => {
  // callback function
});
```